# Emission and absorption of photons by electrons

Tags: experimental-physics, physical-constants, elementary-particles, synchrotron-radiation

Two questions occur at a critical review of the two famous experiments devised by Millikan in 1914, respectively Duane, Hunt and others in 1917-1920, which confirmed the action constant calculated by Planck in 1901.

1. Should the energy equations of both experiments include the energy of photon radiation emitted outside by the electrons during their electromagnetic acceleration from an initial state of relative rest, to a velocity $v ≪ c$ determined by the known equations of energy conversion $hν = mv^2/2$, valid for the photoelectrons emitted from a metal rich in quasi-free electrons having a negligible binding energy and extraction work, respectively $eV = mv^2/2$, valid for the electrons delivered by electronic guns?

In my opinion the answer can only be affirmative, and the best argument is synchrotron radiation emitted by the electrons at each passing through an electromagnetic cavity, wherein they are accelerated by taking over in flight the energy of the field particles of electromagnetic interaction, the photons, therefore exactly the same particles whose energy is taken over by the quasi-free electrons at relative rest in a metal lattice, which become thus free moving photoelectrons. Without this periodical electromagnetic acceleration in a special cavity, inside of which the electrons move in a straight line, synchrotron radiation would not arise, because the electrons in uniformly circular motion in a plane perpendicular to the flux lines of a uniform magnetic field do not radiate (except a very weak radiation caused by their rare incidental collisions with residual gas molecules, which still exist even in the most advanced vacuum), as seen at any electron storage ring in uniform magnetic field. It is therefore beyond doubt the causal connection between synchrotron radiation and electromagnetic acceleration of its emitters, a causal relationship that has to be considered in any acceleration due to the photons, the acknowledged careers of electromagnetic interaction at a distance, whether this acceleration happens in an electron gun, or at an emission of photoelectrons.

2. Should the Millikan’s equation of energy include the energy of photon radiation emitted by the moving photoelectrons during their return to the state of relative rest?

In my opinion the answer can only be affirmative, and the best argument is just the braking radiation (bremsstrahlung) strangely considered only in the other experiment (!). As a matter of fact, whenever the electrons previously accelerated by photons come again at relative rest, no matter how, they can reach their rest mass and energy only by radiating photons which take over their motion mass and energy, another way simply cannot exist.

Well, besides the proper arguments or counterarguments, anyone who wants to answer the two questions should know their huge stake, because if all omissions claimed above are rectified in the energy equations of the two experiments in discussion, conforming to a simple enough reasoning, experimental data of both experiments give an action constant exactly twice smaller than its value always considered in physics! And this bewildering result has to be corroborated with that $2$-factor abusively introduced later in the energy equations of magnetic resonance $hν = 2MB$ and Josephson transitions $hν = 2eV$, just because by using their correct forms $hν = MB$ and $hν = eV$ experimental data would have given a halved value of the acknowledged action constant! Or, it should be noted that magnetic resonance and Josephson transitions remain even today, besides the two older experiments re-examined here, the only **self-consistent** methods able to measure the Planck’s constant exclusively on the basis of their own energy equations. But what is the most important, an ½ reduction now of the action constant means an obligatory reinstatement of the classical model of spinning ring electron with integer spin and inner energy $E_0 = m_0c^2/2$ at rest, replaced in the 1920’s by the point-like electron with intrinsic semi-integer spin and intrinsic rest energy $E_0 = m_0c^2$, therefore a total collapse of quantum relativistic physics and an inevitable return to classical physics of microcosm!

Just because the two questions posted here are, at least in first analysis, the starting point of a chain of essential uncertainties, all involving the same $2$ number, they have to be soundly cleared up, particularly by the specialists in the field. I request them do it.

Answer (score 1):

Real photons are emitted during accelerations,  in synchrotron radiation  and bremsstrahlung and it is a classical electrodynamics prediction .

The [Millikan  experiment](http://physics.aps.org/story/v3/st23) :

> Millikan was the first to determine with great accuracy that the maximum kinetic energy of the ejected electrons obey the equation Einstein had proposed in 1905: namely, 1/2mv2=hf−P, where h is Planck’s constant, f the frequency of the incident light, and P is, in Millikan’s words, “the work necessary to get the electron out of the metal.” Millikan determined h to have the value 6.57x10−27 erg-sec to “a precision of about 0.5 per cent,” a value far better than had been obtained in any previous attempt.

It is the same conundrum as "why the hydrogen atom exists" as the electron should radiate and fall on the proton classically. The emitted electrons do not radiate because it is a quantum transition from a bound state to a free state. One could say, as with the hydrogen atom that it is "syncopated" acceleration coming with quanta. One quantum in and electron out in this case. No corrections for radiation needed, one can say that the quantum frame is the correction for radiation.

The  models for synchrotron radiation  have the electrons  moving in a continuum and are treated accordingly classically. The problem is addressed classically,  no photo electrons there, no h . There exist models that try to address the problem quantum mechanically and they do find deviations from the classical modes. So this cannot be used as an argument on the necessity of radiation. The necessity of radiation comes from classical electromagnetism. Quantum electrodynamics solves such paradoxes, it is why quantum mechanics was invented.

So there is no huge stake because you are misinterpreting data.

Comment: Your answer consists only in some banal clichés, nothing concrete. As for synchrotron radiation and bremsstrahlung, they belong neither to a classical world, and nor to a quantum one, they exist in the real world, so that they are to have a cause and a source for their energy. Please learn first, and then, before writing please read my questions several times and very attentively.

Comment: @SabreTooth - You are right in the main, but your sight is unidirectional.